# Jupyter Notebook can't connect to Kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I usually run jupyter notebook via Ubuntu Linux terminal and it worked just fine until yesterday. Today, when I tried to run it, this error message appeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miraw/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/miraw/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 62, in <module>
    raise ImportError(_("The Jupyter Notebook requires tornado >= 5.0, but you have %s") % tornado.version)
ImportError: The Jupyter Notebook requires tornado >= 5.0, but you have 4.5.3
```

Accordingly, I tried to install tornado 5.0 with the command "pip install tornado==5.0". I am
now able to open jupyter notebook, but a new problem arises: It can't connect to the server.

This is the error message that appears:

> A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.

What I've tried is to uninstall and reinstall it. I've also tried installing version 5.1.1 as other similar problems could be solved like that, but it doesn't work with my problem.

I really don't know what to do, it worked just fine until yesterday.
I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I would do `pip install tornado>=5.0`

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried it just now and it will install tornado 6.1. It opens jupyter notebook but it again can't connect to a server, the error message from jupyter notebook is the same.

Comment: Not really sure. My suggestion would be to use Docker - https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/selecting.html